# Jenkins Pipiline: getting an awk command to play nice

Tags: bash, jenkins, awk, jenkins-pipeline, pypi

I have a usecase to download the tar file of the latest pip package through a url request (not pip download). As such I tried to grep for the latest release by looking at the raw html. So for the raw code of https://pypi.org/project/astroid/#files
I do

```
awk '/release--current">/,/<div class="release"/' html | awk '/"release__version">/{flag=1;next}/<\/p>/{flag=0}flag'|awk '{ gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, ""); print }',
```

This is just grabbing the text between different tages until I finally get what I want. This works fine on the shell but when I put the command in a jenkins pipeline it doesn't return anything. My guess is that its due to escaping:

```
steps {

            cleanWs()

            script {
                if ( params.PKG_VRS ) {
                  httpRequest outputFile: 'myfile', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: 'https://pypi.io/packages/source/{ first letter }/{ package name }/{ package name }-{ version }.tar.gz'
                } else {
                    httpRequest outputFile: 'HTMLFILE', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: 'https://pypi.org/project/astroid/#files'
                    LATEST_VRS = sh (
                        script: """awk '/release--current">/,/<div class="release"/' html | awk '/"release__version">/{flag=1;next}/<\/p>/{flag=0}flag'|awk '{ gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, ""); print }'""",
                        returnStdout: true
                    ).trim()
                    echo "${LATEST_VRS}"
                }
            }

        }
```

I'll be grateful if someone can help me figure out how to escape the awk properly in the Jenkins sh command or if there's a better/easier way to do what I want, which is to grab the latest release version of a PyPi package. There's no url for it from what I can tell and even if it were I would still like to know the nuances in play of using awk in Jenkins.

Comment: Why not start out with making `awk 'BEGIN{print "Hello World"}'` work and then proceed from there?

Comment: PyPI also has a ["Simple API"](https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/api-reference/legacy/) and a [JSON API](https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/api-reference/json/) that might work better for you than the raw HTML.

Comment: See if you call an external script.  This way, you don't have to worry about escaping the quotes and double quotes and such.  In other words, move your awk script to an external script (if possible, I suppose it's not but I don't know anything about Jenkins).

Comment: Thank you all, I will try all the things mentioned above. The api is also helpful but I still want to get awk working as it might prove handy in other tasks